# Is there a way to hide/show columns in lightning-datable based on screen size?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable, visibility

We wanted to hide a few columns present in the datable on mobile.
We are using lightning-datatable, as this is standard we can't use media queries on it to hide or show a particular column based on the device. Is there a way we can acheive this in LWC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can detect the user client's [form factor](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_client_form_factor), then decide what fields to display based on that:

```
import FORM_FACTOR from '@salesforce/client/formFactor';
```

...

```
const columns = {
  Large: [ { ... }, ... ],
  Medium: [ { ... }, ... ],
  Small: [ { ... }, ... ],
};

export default class MyComponentName extends LightningElement {
  columns = columns[FORM_FACTOR];
}
```

Comment: It helped. Thank you so much!